# JPA Grouping based on a column and collecting results in a list

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data JPA I have a table that looks like

```
    NAME            AGE     GANG 
---------------------------------
Iron Man            46      1    
Black Panther       45      1    
Captain America     96      2    
Ant Man             40      2    
The hulk            48      3
```

I want to map this to the following class without the N+1 selects problem

```
public class Gang {
    private int id;
    private List<Member> members;
}

public class Member {
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

I tried self join with @OneToMany but I couldn't get through. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this problem by making sure that the initial query fetches all the data needed to load the objects we need in their appropriately initialized state. One way of doing this is using an `HQL` fetch join. We use the `HQL`

the N+1 problem can happen if the first query populates the primary object and the second query populates all the child objects for each of the unique primary objects returned.

To resolve `N+1 SELECTs` problem  use `HQL` `join fetch`

```
"from  Gang gang join fetch gang.member Member"
```

Now in result generated SQL you can see the `Left outer join` of `Member` `entity` on `Gang` `entity`.